# Qsort not displaying in correct order

Tags: c, pointers, struct, compare, qsort

I use qsort to sort my array of ProcEntry pointers and am trying to get them to be sorted in
ascending order but for some reason only a couple of the pointers are out of place.
I've tried multiple types of comparators for my defaultSort function but cannot seem to figure out why some values are not being sorted.

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#include "ProcEntry.h"

#define MAX_PATH_LENGTH 4096

#define UNUSED(x) (void)x

static int defaultFilter(const struct dirent *current){
    return isdigit(current->d_name[0]);
}
static int defaultSort(const void * procEntryPtr1, const void * procEntryPtr2){
    /* Dereference the parameters to access the ProcEntry pointers */
    ProcEntry *ProcEntry1 = *(ProcEntry **)procEntryPtr1; 
    ProcEntry *ProcEntry2 = *(ProcEntry **)procEntryPtr2;

    // if((ProcEntry1)->pid < (ProcEntry2)->pid) return -1;
    // if((ProcEntry1)->pid == (ProcEntry2)->pid) return 0;
    // if((ProcEntry1)->pid > (ProcEntry2)->pid) return 1;
   
    return (ProcEntry2->pid > ProcEntry1->pid) - (ProcEntry2->pid < ProcEntry1->pid);
    //return ProcEntry1 < ProcEntry2 ? -1 : ProcEntry1 > ProcEntry2 ? 1 : 0;
}

int main (int argc, char * argv[]) {

    struct dirent **namelist;
    int n;
    int opt;
    int print = 0; // 0 for no 1 for yes

    /* Declare filterFunction pointer */
    int(*filterFunction)(const struct dirent *);
    filterFunction = defaultFilter;
    /* Declare filterFunction pointer */
    int(*sortFunction)(const void *, const void *);
    sortFunction = defaultSort;
    char* dir = "/proc";

    /* Variable Fields */

    while((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "d:pczh")) != -1){
        switch(opt){
            case 'd':
                dir = argv[2];
                if(strcmp(dir, "/proc") == 0){
                    filterFunction = defaultFilter;
                } else {
                    filterFunction = NULL;
                }
                print = 1;
                break;
            case 'p':   //Part 3
                print = 1;
                filterFunction = defaultFilter;
                sortFunction = defaultSort;
                break;
            case 'c':   //Part 3
                break;
            case 'z':   //Part 3
                break;
            case 'h':
                print = 0;
                printf("Usage: %s [-d <path>] [-p] [-c] [-z] [-h]\n", argv[0]);
                printf("\t-d <path> Directory containing proc entries (default: /proc)\n");
                printf("\t-p        Display proc entries sorted by pid (default)\n");
                printf("\t-c        Display proc entries sorted by command lexicographically\n");
                printf("\t-z        Display ONLY proc entries in the zombie state \n");
                printf("\t-h        Display this help message\n");
                break;
            default:
                fprintf(stderr,"Error: Invalid Option Specified\n");
                fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s [-d <path>] [-p] [-c] [-z] [-h]\n", argv[0]);
                printf("\t-d <path> Directory containing proc entries (default: /proc)\n");
                printf("\t-p        Display proc entries sorted by pid (default)\n");
                printf("\t-c        Display proc entries sorted by command lexicographically\n");
                printf("\t-z        Display ONLY proc entries in the zombie state \n");
                printf("\t-h        Display this help message\n");
        }
    }
    if(argc > 6){
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: ./myps [-d <path>] [-p] [-c] [-z] [-h]\n");
        printf("\t-d <path> Directory containing proc entries (default: /proc)\n");
        printf("\t-p        Display proc entries sorted by pid (default)\n");
        printf("\t-c        Display proc entries sorted by command lexicographically\n");
        printf("\t-z        Display ONLY proc entries in the zombie state \n");
        printf("\t-h        Display this help message\n");
    }

    n = scandir(dir, &namelist, filterFunction, alphasort);
    qsort(namelist, n, sizeof(ProcEntry *), sortFunction);
    if (n < 0)
        perror("scandir");
    else {
        while (n--) {
            printf("%s\n", namelist[n]->d_name);
            free(namelist[n]);
        }
        free(namelist);
    }

    /* display the names on stdout stream */
    if(print == 1){
        print = 0;
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            fprintf(stdout,"%s\n", namelist[i]->d_name);
        }
    }
        
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please update your question to be a  [mre].  This is not minimal and reference a custom header file that you didn't include.  You don't tell us how you run this (prefer hard-coding a test case).

Comment: `if (n < 0)` test makes more sense _before_ `qsort()` - else risk UB.

Comment: Where and how is `ProcEntry` defined?

Comment: scandir sorts the namelist internally with qsort if I read the man page correctly.  Why do you want to qsort it again?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

You ask `qsort()` to sort a `namelist` (`struct dirent **`).  It's odd that you say the `size` of each element is `sizeof(ProcEntry *)` instead of `sizeof(*namelist)` but I guess that's ok as pointers are the same size.  Your sort function, however, is passed two `struct dirent **`, and while you have not told us what `ProcEntry` is, the cast `*(ProcEntry **)` is almost certainly incorrect.

This sorts the result by name (`d_name`) with a separate `qsort()`:

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int dirent_cmp(const void *a, const void *b) {
    return strcmp(
        (*(struct dirent **) a)->d_name,
        (*(struct dirent **) b)->d_name
    );
}

int main (int argc, char * argv[]) {
    struct dirent **namelist;
    int n = scandir(".", &namelist, NULL, NULL);
    qsort(namelist, n, sizeof(*namelist), dirent_cmp);
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", namelist[i]->d_name);
    }
}
```

As noted `scandir()` will sort the result for you internally if you specify a compare function as the 4th argument (renamed the compare function to `dirent_cmp2()` to highlight that the declaration uses different types of `a` and `b`):

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int dirent_cmp2(const struct dirent **a, const struct dirent **b) {
    return strcmp((*a)->d_name, (*b)->d_name);
}

int main (int argc, char * argv[]) {
    struct dirent **namelist;
    int n = scandir(".", &namelist, NULL, dirent_cmp2);
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", namelist[i]->d_name);
    }
}
```